# getting Cross-Origin Request Blocked when calling webmethod

Tags: .net, ajax, web-services, asmx, webmethod

i create a Web Method in .asmx file and hosted it on server,when i'm calling it from any remote application that time i'm getting this error:

```
 detailed error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.200.55/ChatApp.asmx/UserLogin. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

my WebMethod .cs code is as:

```
   [WebMethod]
    public string UserLogin(string u_name,string user_pwd)
    {
        string result = "true";
        if (u_name == "unicolumn" && user_pwd=="admin")
        {
            result = "true";
        }

    else
        {
            result = "false";

        }
        return result;

    }
```

and my ajax call method is here:

```
function apiLogin()
{
debugger;

 var UserName = document.getElementById('txtUserName').value;
   var PWD = document.getElementById('txtUserPWD').value;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://192.168.200.55/ChatApp.asmx/UserLogin",
    data: "{'u_name':'" + UserName + "','user_pwd':'" + PWD + "'}", //{u_name:UserName,user_pwd:PWD},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {

           alert(response.d);
        },
    failure: function(Response) {
        alert(Response.d);
    }
});

}
```

when i'm testing it by running visual studio application it is working fine, in case of calling it from another application, generating an error related with Cross-Origin Request Blocked. 
can someone please help me to figure out what i'm missing here.... thanks in advance.